# Get Unicode (USC-2) values for a string in Excel or OfficeCalc

Tags: excel, unicode, openoffice-calc

I am trying to use an API for messaging. For my particular application, I need to get the USC-2 values of all the characters before I can use the API.
Please tell how to get USC-2 values for all the characters of a given string. For my application, I will be typing my string in a cell of spreadsheet and would like to see the USC-2 value of the string in another cell as I type.

Example: If I type "नमस्ते" in one cell I should get the output as "0928‎092E‎0938‎094D‎0924‎0947" in another cell.

In excel and OfficeCalc there is a function "UNICODE" which does something similar but it applies only to the first character of the string. I would like to convert the entire string into 4 digit Unicode values.

[API Link](http://www.smscountry.com/downloads/SMSCountry_HTTP_API.pdf) - Page 6 - section 6.2

Comment: Not possible using sheet formulas only. A macro programming language is needed. What programming language will be usable for you? Also why the Excel tag? Is Excel using VBA also an option?

Comment: Want to do in excel because already using it for the said application. Also want to draw dynamic data from input string like the number of characters and how many actual SMSes it will consume. Also, it will be able to store my list of recipients. After getting all the data in excel I am planning to use perl to read excel file and invoke API.

Comment: I am not used to VBA

Comment: Why the downvote even if it is not possible in Excel?

Comment: Excel solution provided. Will try Openoffice Calc later, no access to Openoffice Calc just now.

Comment: Openoffice Calc solution provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution without macro is using helper cells.

Example

[image]

Formulas:

In `B1`:

```
=MID($A1,COLUMN(A1),1)
```

copied to right until results are empty.

In `B2`:

```
=DEC2HEX(UNICODE(B1),4)
```

copied to right until #VALUE error appears.

In `B3`:

```
=B2
```

and in `C3`:

```
=B3&C2
```

copied to right until #VALUE error appears.

Using the following user defined function (Excel VBA), this can be achieved using

```
=ucscode(A1)
```

within a cell.

Function:

```
Public Function ucscode(s As String) As String
 For i = 1 To Len(s)
  ucscode = ucscode & Application.Dec2Hex(AscW(Mid(s, i, 1)), 4)
 Next
End Function
```

---

With Openoffice Calc the formula solution will be the same as with Excel. Of course the error is Err:504 and not #VALUE.

The user defined function with starbasic could be:

```
Public Function ucscode(s As String) As String
 Dim sresult as String
 For i = 1 To Len(s)
  sresult = sresult & right("0000" & hex(asc(mid(s, i,1))), 4)
 Next
 ucscode = sresult
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is similar to @Axel Richter's:

1. In cell B1, enter `=IF(LEN($A$1)>=ROW(),DEC2HEX(UNICODE(MID($A$1,ROW(),1)),4),"")`.
2. Fill this formula down to row B30.
3. In cell C1, enter the formula `=CONCATENATE(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,B10,B11,B12,B13,B14,B15,B16,B17,B18,B19,B20,B21,B22,B23,B24,B25,B26,B27,B28,B29,B30)`.

Now enter the string to be converted in cell A1.  It will work for up to 30 characters.

[image: calc sheet formulas]

Keep in mind that in recent versions of LibreOffice (and Excel I think), you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to see the Unicode value of a character.

Of course, this would be easier in Perl.